# Wordpress theme not appears as shown

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been trying to develop my first WordPress theme. When I added a theme "primer" and started customizing it, it appears as an image.

[The primer theme appearing as shown not as it is shown in demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkNZu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a little more detail. Normally themes are generally blank and often never look like the picture. Its up to you to use the themes composer, purchase a composer if your theme does not have one, or hand codde the site only using the theme for an overall look. For instance my theme I use a mix. I installed it and got a blank theme. I then used the composer to add elements and build out the page. Some themes even offer templates which is likely what you saw when you bought the theme. Your theme should have some sort of templates for free or premium templates for purchase you can add on top of your theme to get a prebuilt layout. I would highly enocourage watching a few youtube videos over themes and customizations and using envato.com to our advantage. Wordpress is a beast most people dont realize. Its not a change words and done. There are multiple other sites for that. I just finished my first one and its a bear. It take patience creativity and a basic understanding of Wordpress to operate, and some coding experience would greatly benefit to.